# How to wire two wall plates together to form pass through?

Tags: networking

Pretty simple question I think, I'm just not sure how to do it. My cabling experience is one marathon weekend of rewiring a server closet for a 4 story building, but we had a lot of help and that was 9 years ago.

So here is the scenario. We're trying to pass ethernet through a wall using your standard wall plates. So on one side we have: Modem/Router -> cat5 -> wall plate. On the other side of the same wall we have: wall plate -> cat5 -> Computer. The cat5 cables are your normal pre-terminated retail stuff. So the question is, how do we wire the two wall plates together? Do we just run them straight across, match the colors on the jacks or something else entirely?

EDIT: This is a simple home install so there isn't a a patch panel or anything. We just wanted a way to get ethernet to the other side of the wall without running through the door, etc.

Comment: The wall plates should be terminated on a punch down block somewhere. It would be very odd if they weren't. If you can find the punch down block you can connect the ports to s switch in order to connect the equipment to.

Comment: wall plate to wall plate would be [crossover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_cable). joeqwerty saying (i assume) a [path panel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_panel) the smartest option. Read into [TIA/EIA-568](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIA/EIA-568) for a start to network cable termination.

Comment: @joeqwerty - Thanks for the suggestion, but this is just a simple home setup. I edited the question to reflect that. There is no block or anything, we're just trying to get ethernet from one room to the other without running cables under the door, baseboards, etc.

Comment: @gwillie - Thank you for the information!

Comment: I'm not understanding what the wall plates are connected to if there's no patch panel. Are they not wired at all then?

Comment: You probably want something like this - https://www.computercablestore.com/rj45-cat5e-keystone-jack-pass-through-panel-mount-black

Comment: @joeqwerty They're wired to each other. Imagine you need to get a cable from one room to the adjacent room and there is no door. You could just punch a hole in the wall and run a standard cable through. Instead, we're using two wall platers on adjacent/parallel walls to "pass" the cable through the wall. I hope that explains it a little better.

Comment: @joeqwerty Thank you, that's exactly what we need. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standards dictate you use the T-568B color coding on the wall plates.  All wall plates should be simple straight through, there is no twisting on any of them.  This is true for patch panels or not.  Patch panels will follow this coding as well.

The two color codes - T568A or T568B.
In the USA, the standard is B for networking. You can use either, but stick to one.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the 568B standard. The punch down block on the back of the wall plates should be marked to show which conductor goes where. This is simple and straight through since all you are doing is basically extending a cable.